# How to convert Decimal to String? How to eliminate type casting error?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
//Decimal to String in lable.text control//   
 protected void gvProd_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        decimal total = 0;
        decimal profit = 0;

        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {

            Label lblTotal = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lbltotal");
            total = Convert.ToDecimal(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "AchievedPer"));
            string stotal = Convert.ToDecimal(total).ToString();

            lblTotal.Text =Convert.ToString(total).ToString();//Error occurs here //'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
        }
 }
```

Comment: Is `total` null in that line ?

Comment: it looks like `lbltotal` is not found.

Comment: `total` is `decimal`. How can be `null` without `decimal?`?

Comment: `Convert.ToString(total)` is equivalent to `total.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)`. I don't believe this line throws a `NullReferenceException`. And `CurrentCulture` can **never** be `null`. Looks like your `FindControl` method can't find anything and it returns `null` to `lblTotal`.

Comment: @SonerGönül `lblTotal` is **null**

Comment: It seems that you are unsure about what a Convert.ToString calls returns. If I were you I would add another ToString() Just to be sure to get a string from a string from a string..... The problem is lblTotal. The FindControl has not found anything

Comment: @Selman22 Yeah, that's the only way to get NRE.

Comment: In addition to code, you should also describe your intent in addition to the question in the title.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
if (lblTotal != null)
  lblTotal.Text = Convert.ToString(total);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Label lblTotal = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lbltotal");
....
lblTotal.Text =Convert.ToString(total).ToString();
```

This last line fails not because the conversion failed, but because `lblTotal` is null.

Which means there's no control named `lbltotal`. Perhaps that was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

try to use `Decimal.TryParse()` method. I suspect your code `DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "AchievedPer")` is `Null`
try this code hope it will help.

```
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {

        Label lblTotal = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lbltotal");
        if (lblTotal != null)
        {
            total = Decimal.TryParse(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "AchievedPer"));
            string stotal = Convert.ToDecimal(total).ToString();
            lblTotal.Text =total.ToString();//Error occurs here //'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'            
        }
    }
```

Comment: But the error is not on that line.

Comment: yes you are right error is occurring due to this line `(Label)e.Row.FindControl("lbltotal");` may be this label doesn't exist.

Comment: ok if error is not at `DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "AchievedPer")` then how it's throwing an exception at last line why not at this `total = Convert.ToDecimal(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "AchievedPer"));`

Comment: The exception occurs on the line `lblTotal.Text =Convert.ToString(total).ToString();` as the OP says in the question, which is likely due to `lblTotal` being null.

Comment: ah ok i overlooked the left side thanks for correcting me

Comment: You are welcome. Also `total` is a non-nullable decimal, you don't have to do this `if(total !=null)`

Answer (score 0):

```
//Decimal to String in lable.text control//   
protected void gvProd_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
     decimal total = 0;
     decimal profit = 0;

     if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
     {
         object objAchievedPer = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "AchievedPer");             
         Label lblTotal = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lbltotal");

        if(lblTotal != null)
        {
              if(objAchievedPer != null)
              {
                    total = Convert.ToDecimal(objAchievedPer);
              }

          lblTotal.Text = total.ToString();
        }          
     }
}
```